# Crystal Report Summarizing Subtotals for Repeat Customer Rate

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to create a report for in Crystal Reports based on a nested MySQL query although I am not sure if it is possible to recreate in CR. I am running CR 2016 Support Pack 2 v 14.2. Here was the nested query I am trying to imitate in CR.

```
SELECT
    count(DISTINCT a.cust_sid) AS numCurCust,
    SUM(CASE WHEN a.prevCust > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS numRptCust,
    SUM(CASE WHEN a.prevCust = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS numNewCust,
    SUM(a.curCust) AS numCurOrders,
    SUM(CASE WHEN a.prevCust > 0 THEN a.curCust ELSE 0 END) as numCurOrdersFromPrevCust,
    SUM(CASE WHEN a.prevCust = 0 THEN a.curCust ELSE 0 END) AS numCurOrdersFromNewCust
FROM (
SELECT
    i.cust_sid,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN i.created_date >= '2013-01-01 00:00:00' AND i.created_date <= '2015-12-31 00:00:00' THEN CONCAT(i.invc_sid," ",DATE_FORMAT(i.created_date,'%Y-%m-%d')) END) AS curCust,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN i.created_date <= '2013-01-01 00:00:00' THEN CONCAT(i.invc_sid," ",DATE_FORMAT(i.created_date,'%Y-%m-%d')) END) AS prevCust
FROM invoice i 
LEFT JOIN invc_item ii ON i.invc_sid = ii.invc_sid
LEFT JOIN invc_tender it ON i.invc_sid = it.invc_sid
WHERE i.invc_no != 0 AND 
    i.invc_type = 0 AND
    i.store_no = 0 AND 
    i.cust_sid IS NOT NULL AND 
    ii.invc_sid IS NOT NULL AND 
    ii.QTY > 0 AND
    (ii.QTY *  ii.price * ((100 - IFNULL(i.DISC_PERC, 0)) / 100)) > 0 AND 
    it.tender_type != 5
GROUP BY i.cust_sid
HAVING curCust > 0)a
```

I currently have Crystal Reports set with a date range parameter and I am then grouping results by `{INVOICE.CUST_SID}`. I have two columns one for `curCust` which is a running total using a distinct count of `{INVOICE.INVC_SID}`, evaluated on `{INVOICE.CREATED_DATE} = {?DateRange}`, and a reset on change of `{INVOICE.CUST_SID}`. I have another column for `prevCust` which is also a running total using a distinct count of `{INVOICE.INVC_SID}`, evaluated using `{INVOICE.CREATED_DATE} <= MINIMUM({?DateRange})`, and also reset on change of `{INVOICE.CUST_SID}`.

Where I am stuck at is creating a formula based on the ending running total for each columns before the reset. If both `curCust` and `prevCust` is `> 0` THEN display 1 in a third column which could be summarized using SUM to get 'Total # Rpt Cust'. If prevCust = 0 and curCust > 0 then in a fourth column display 1 which could be summarized using `SUM` to get `Total # New Cust`. Also I need two other columns to count the distinct `{INVOICE.INVC_SID}` for both new and unique customers. But I can't figure out how to create a formula based on ending running total nor can I figure out how to summarize a formula field based the ending running total.

Could anybody point me in the right direction as to how I could accomplish any of this?